# Как анимировать сетку из точек?

Tags: анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в теории могу это сделать стандартными средствами, но будет как-то странно иметь в HTML-документе целую кучу пустых элементов. С помощью чего это делается? Canvas? Может кто-нибудь показать как?

Comment: Только что заметил, что ещё точки на синем фоне становятся светлее...короче это мне точно не по зубам )

Comment: Вообще, судя по Вашим ответам - по зубам, не вижу тут ничего суперсложного, на одних транзишенах можно собрать, имхо

Comment: @StrangerintheQ свойство `width` у паттерна можно как-нибудь анимировать ? https://jsfiddle.net/y7posbr5/

Comment: к сожалению jsfiddle у меня на телефоне не открывается

Answer (score 1):

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const w = canvas.width
const h = canvas.height

const start_time = now()
const duration = 1.4

update()

function now() {
  return Date.now() / 1000
}

function easeInOutQuad(t) {
  return t < 0.5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t
}

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
}

function drawPoint(x, y, r) {
  context.beginPath()
  context.fillStyle = 'indigo'
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  context.fill()
}

function drawPoints(n, m, t) {
  const x_step = w / (m * t)
  const y_step = h / n

  for (let i = 1; i < n * t; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < m; j++) {
      const x = x_step * j
      const y = y_step * i
      drawPoint(x, y, 2)
    }
  }
}

function update() {
  clear()
  const t = (now() - start_time) / duration
  const te = easeInOutQuad(t)
  drawPoints(10, 20, te)

  if (t < 1) requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 70px);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=240 height=140></canvas>
```